# Ruby print JSON value - no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to print only the value of a JSON and I'm getting the error `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

`puts test.class`

```
Azure::Armrest::ArmrestCollection
```

Here is the output of the varaible and I want to print only the `quantity` value.

`puts test`

```
[----] I, [2022-08-23T08:59:20.279357 #550:bc494]  INFO -- automation: Method STDOUT: {"id":"/subscriptions/123456/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates/Daily_BRSDT_20220801_0000","name":"Daily_BRSDT_20220801_0000","type":"Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregate","properties":{"subscriptionId":"123456","usageStartTime":"2022-07-31T00:00:00+00:00","usageEndTime":"2022-08-01T00:00:00+00:00","meterName":"Data Transfer Out","meterRegion":"North America","meterCategory":"Bandwidth","meterSubCategory":"Inter-Region","unit":"1 GB","instanceData":"{\"Microsoft.Resources\":{\"resourceUri\":\"/subscriptions/123456/resourceGroups/cloud-shell-storage-centralindia/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ubuntu975\",\"location\":\"eastus\",\"additionalInfo\":{\"PipelineType\":\"v2\",\"DataTransferDirection\":\"DataTrOut\"}}}","meterId":"dbefcfc1-e3f6-409b-be6d-9cd7b00724a5","infoFields":{},"quantity":9.052455425262451e-07}}
[----] I, [2022-08-23T08:59:20.280435 #550:bc494]  INFO -- automation: Method STDOUT: {"id":"/subscriptions/123456/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates/Daily_BRSDT_20220801_0000","name":"Daily_BRSDT_20220801_0000","type":"Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregate","properties":{"subscriptionId":"123456","usageStartTime":"2022-07-31T00:00:00+00:00","usageEndTime":"2022-08-01T00:00:00+00:00","meterName":"Dynamic Public IP","meterCategory":"Virtual Network","meterSubCategory":"IP Addresses","unit":"1 Hour","instanceData":"{\"Microsoft.Resources\":{\"resourceUri\":\"/subscriptions/123456/resourceGroups/cloud-shell-storage-centralindia/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/Ubuntu975-publicIp\",\"location\":\"eastus\",\"additionalInfo\":{\"IpAddress\":\"20.25.57.9\",\"PlatformType\":\"V2-Agg\"}}}","meterId":"f114cb19-ea64-40b5-bcd7-aee474b62853","infoFields":{},"quantity":1.0}}
```

`puts test["properties"]["quantity"]`

```
[----] E, [2022-08-23T08:59:28.949873 #544:b6620] ERROR -- automation: <AEMethod getcostusage> [no implicit conversion of String into Integer]
/CloudForms_Essentials/Integration/Azure/StateMachines/getCostUsage:79:in `[]'
/CloudForms_Essentials/Integration/Azure/StateMachines/getCostUsage:79:in `<main>'
[----] I, [2022-08-23T08:59:28.974301 #544:ac260]  INFO -- automation: <AEMethod [/CloudForms_Essentials/Integration/Azure/StateMachines/getCostUsage]> Ending
```

If I try JSON.parse(test) then I get this error.

```
[----] E, [2022-08-23T09:18:39.022825 #553:bcaac] ERROR -- automation: <AEMethod getcostusage> [no implicit conversion of Azure::Armrest::ArmrestCollection into String]
```

Comment: You error seems to suggest `test["properties"]` is  seen as a string. When you then do `test["properties"]["quantity"]`, it tries to take an index of a string, but you give the string "quantity" instead. Perhaps you are missing a `JSON.parse(...)` somewhere?

Comment: Updated the question with the output of json.parse. I get the following error. Any idea how to resolve this? `no implicit conversion of Azure::Armrest::ArmrestCollection into String`

Comment: Can you try `p test["properties"]`? (insttead of `puts test["properties"]["quantity"]`)

Comment: I get the error `[----] E, [2022-08-23T09:24:51.117535 #553:bd90c] ERROR -- automation: <AEMethod getcostusage> [no implicit conversion of String into Integer]` when I try `p test["properties"]` That is before JSON.parse. After JSON.parse the error is `no implicit conversion of Azure::Armrest::ArmrestCollection into String`

Comment: oh i think i see now. `class ArmrestCollection` inherits from `Array`. It's also probably the reason why your `puts test` shows 2 loggings. Could you try `p test[0]["properties"]["quantity"]`? It should print the quantity of the first element

Comment: That seems to work but it only prints the first item quantity. As you can see I have 2 or more times.  How can I print quantity of everything?

Comment: See my answer for a working method!

Answer (score 0):

`test` is an instance of `ArmrestCollection`, which inherits from `Array` class (as can be viewed [here](https://github.com/ManageIQ/azure-armrest/blob/3a9ff6ce732a517293ee27c0c18ad985c09c77a2/lib/azure/armrest/armrest_collection.rb)).

To print the quantity of all elements, you can iterate it and print them each individually:

```rb
test.each do |element|
   puts element["properties"]["quantity"]
end
```

Comment: Nice that's great. Any idea how can sum up all values if needed? I can post a another question but I'm trying to do something like `a.inject{ |sum,x| sum + x }`

Comment: you could do `test.inject{|sum,x| sum + x["properties"]["quantity"]}`

Comment: Oh I just found out that some values are printed as in a scientific format. `automation: Method STDOUT: 4.0e-06`.

Comment: Is there a way to convert these values into a proper decimal?

Comment: You can use something like `puts "%.6f" % element["properties"]["quantity"]`,where the precision is determined by the `6` (so in this case 6 digits after the decimal).

Comment: Cool. Can I sum within the `test.each do |element|`? instead of the previous suggestion? Because that returns ` <AEMethod getcostusage> [undefined method `+' for #<Azure::Armrest::Billing::Usage:0x00005571dcddfc40>]`

Comment: yeah of course. Just initialize the sum outside the loop (above) eg: `total = 0`. And put in your loop `total += element["properties"]["quantity"]`